# Querying can not select table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new on Postgres and I don't understand I can't run select on pgAdmin4?  The tables existed on each schema and when I do,

```
select * from schema.table_name;
```

I get an error: relation "schema.table_name" does not exist

```
line 1: select * from schema.table_name
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

What I did wrong here? Any help would be appreciate.
Also, most of my post was deleted.  can you point me out how to create a new post and/or can't now allow to ask questions here?

Comment: If you go through the sidebar to the table (for me it's `Servers -> postgres -> Databases -> {database-name} -> Schemas -> Tables -> {table-name}`) and Right click -> View/Edit Data, what happens?

Comment: Do `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'` to see if it exists, if not then that is the problem.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist?s=1|208.5301) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941922) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125679) or any other of the [many questions with that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+relation+does+not+exist)